# is it bad to use flex on css styling?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to know that if i use flex on CSS style sheet will it not work properly on other uncommon browsers and devices? I tested on chrome and Firefox it works fine. but hard to check with all browsers. I need some expert advice.

Comment: Have you checked [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)?

Comment: The only way to know if anything works in CSS is to test in all browsers. The question is what browsers do you need to support. The so called "Evergreen Browsers" will be fine, if it needs to work in anything else charge for it.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It might cause a problem on some really old browsers, but they are negligible.